# Breakpoints not working in Fortran code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fortran

I'm new to VS Code and I'm having trouble with debugging a fortran code, as breakpoints never work and are skipped as if they were not there.

I've made a test program with the same problem:

```
program test

implicit none
real :: x

x = 10.0
print*, x

end program test
```

If I place a breakpoint at the print statement, the debugger does not stop.

During the run the breakpoint becomes grey and I get this message

```
Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.
```

This is *tasks.json*

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "compile",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gfortran",
        "args": [
            "test.f90"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cdw": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    }
]
}
```

and this *launch.json*

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Run GDB",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program":"${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "preLaunchTask": "compile",
    },
    {
        "name": "Intel Debug Attach",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
}
```

I installed the extensions C/C++, fortran by Xavier Hahn, Modern Fortran by Miguel Carvajal, Fortran IntelliSense, and Fortran Breakpoint Support.

Is anyone willing to give me a hand?

Comment: How do you place the breakpoint?

Comment: @VladimirF by clicking next to the line number in the editor and placing a red dot, I checked and it appears in the breakpoints list and it is active

Comment: Update: during the run the breakpoint becomes grey and I get this message "Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @VladimirF Linux Mint 20.3

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I cannot put breakpoints in the subroutines contained in a module either.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the debug symbols from your binary. You need to include `-g` as an argument in the `tasks.json`

```json
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "compile",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gfortran",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-Wall",
            "test.f90"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cdw": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    }
]
}
```

As a side note you only need the [Modern Fortran](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortran-lang.linter-gfortran) extension

---

Full disclosure I am one of the devs of the extension