# Breakpoints cannot be set when compiling Fortran with VSCODE

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

I'm new to Visual Studio Code and I'm having trouble with debugging a Fortran code, as I can't set breakpoints in my code in VS Code in Windows 11

I put the code I used for my tests below.

```
! main program
program main

    use InputRead
    implicit none

    CALL InputRead_init()

end program main
```

Normally, vscode can set breakpoints by clicking on the white space on the left side of the code, but when I moved the mouse over the white space on the left side of the code, there was no red dot representing the breakpoint, and I couldn't right click to set "breakpoint" or use "Run here function".

This is tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "gfortran",
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}\\Common\\*.f90",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}\\Module\\InputRead\\*.f90",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}\\*.f90",        
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ]
}
```

This is launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Fortran Launch (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "x86",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "gfortran",
        },
        {
            "name": "Intel Debug Attach",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is settings.json

```
{
 "[fortran]": {
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
},
"[fortran_fixed-form]": {
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
},
 "[FortranFreeForm]": {
     "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
 },
 "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "disabled"
 }
```

I installed the extensions C/C++, fortran by Xavier Hahn, Modern Fortran by Miguel Carvajal, Fortran IntelliSense, and Fortran Breakpoint Support. And my version of gfortran is gcc version 8.1.0.

This is the output at the bottom.

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 4320.0x8d8]
[New Thread 4320.0x4e88]
[New Thread 4320.0x577c]
[New Thread 4320.0x4acc]

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004038a8 in main (argc=1, argv=0xf11780) at E:\Fortran\test\test.f90:5
5       use InputRead
Loaded 'C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'D:\mingw64\opt\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'D:\mingw64\bin\libquadmath-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
[Thread 4320.0x4e88 exited with code 0]
[Thread 4320.0x577c exited with code 0]
[Thread 4320.0x4acc exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 4320) exited normally]
The program 'E:\Fortran\test\test' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

I tried to debug using the "Start debugging" function on the vscode menu bar. I successfully compiled an executable file, but there was no way to debug it step by step.
I expect that I can use the debugging function to implement step-by-step debugging

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71160460/breakpoints-not-working-in-fortran-code-in-visual-studio-code?rq=2 you only need the Modern Fortran extension. Are there any error or warning messages in the output boxes on the bottom?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I uninstalled the other extension and only kept Modern Fortran extension. Now my code is not highlighted., and I still can't add breakpoints. I read the other answer you provided and I see a difference in the issues he and I face. He seems to be able to add breakpoints, but breakpoints don't work, and I can't add breakpoints at all.

Comment: Do not use comments for important information, [edit] your question instead. I really suggest recommend the [tour].

Comment: I am not saying the other linked question is the same. If I did, I would mark this one as duplicate, but I didn't. Nevertheless the recommendation to use Modern Fortran only (with fortls) is, I think, important and comes from a develooer of the extension.

Comment: Ok OK, I added some information in the description of the problem, thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you only need Modern Fortran as an extension (install the pre-release version please). There are some limitations if you are using a debugger on Windows but that should only apply for the Intel compilers.

You build task i.e. tasks.json I think is not robust, since it uses regex, instead of a proper build tool like GNU Make or CMake that form a dependency tree to compile your sources. That means you cannot guarantee the the modules used between source files are the most up-to-date versions. This would definitely cause the debugger to not work.

On Windows 10 I was able to set breaking points and step through code (with modules) perfectly fine, so please post a full Minimal Working Example if you want us to have a closer look.